# File not found exception, not sure what is the cause

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I am supposed to create a string array using input from a text file, but I can't get the text file to read properly. I have the text file and the program in the same folder, what am I doing wrong?

```
package A2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class a2main {
public static final Scanner SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] winners;

public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException{ //main method
    String teamName = getInput();
    createArray();
    int wins = calcTeamWins(teamName);
    printWins(teamName, wins);
}

public static int calcTeamWins(String TeamName){ //Scans the array and returns team wins
    return 0;
}

public static String getInput(){ // Method to get input from user.
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the team you'd like to choose.");
    return SCANNER.next();
}

public static String[] createArray() throws FileNotFoundException{ //Method used to create and fill array of winners.
    final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 104;
    String[] winnerArray = new String[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    File WSW = new File("WorldSeriesWinners.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(WSW);

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH-1; i++){
        while(inputFile.hasNext()){
        winnerArray[i] = inputFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(winnerArray[i]);
    }
    }
    inputFile.close();
    return winnerArray;
}
public static void printWins(String TeamName, int Wins){ //Method used to print team anem + wins
    System.out.println("The " + TeamName + " have won " + Wins + " World Series.");
}

}
```

The text file it is supposed to read is WorldSeriesWinners.txt The file is a multiline txt with a string on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between where Java is being executed, and where the file is. It isn't looking from the same directory that the class is in.

Since it is packaged, you need to add that to the path.

Try something like:

```
   new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/A2/" + "WorldSeriesWinners.txt")
```

Comment: Better still, `new File("A2/WorldSeriesWinners.txt")`. Or move the file up out of A2.

Comment: that is a true @EJP